# Why the alert is showing undefined after fred flinston? and what properties does "const" in ES6 have?

Tags: javascript, string, function, variables, let

```js
let a = 'Fred Flinstone'; // This is a global variable
function alpha() {
alert(a);
}
alert(alpha());
```

why the following code displaying undefined after displaying fred flinston?
and what properties does "const" in ES6 have and what is meant by " referencing to memory " in const?
Thanks

Comment: @Ivar Yes Ivar, Thank you but the second part of the question(const) remain unclear

Comment: Only one question per question, please. There is also a duplicate for `const`, depending on exactly what you mean by it.

Comment: @VLAZ Can you give the link of the post containing const?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after you use alert(alpha()),this code will do 2 steps:
1.get the return value from alpha()
2.execute the alert function

Because there is no return code from the function **alpha** , so it return 'undefined' and which will be print in the alert box

Comment: please tell also the "const" part of question